# My ubuntuone is broken, what is the problem?

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one, dbus

I am on 10.10 and u1sdtool seems to be completely broken. I reinstalled it, no change. I can add my PC to the account, but it is added twice(!) every time I tried. So I have my netbook and two times my PC in the account. The netbook with 10.04 has no problems.

Below is the error msg I get when attempting to startup Ubuntu One on the command line.

> desktop:~$ u1sdtool --status
>
> Oops, an error ocurred:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   Failure: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
>   desktop:~$

Starting it from the Me Menu has the same effect, the HDD will get really busy for a minute and then nothing happens, the client will not start.

Nothing in the syslog or anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Are the only lines in ~/.cache/ubuntuone/log/syncdaemon.log look like

```
$date - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.VM.MD - DEBUG - metadata version: 6
$date - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.fsm - INFO - loading updated metadata
```

If yes, then this may be the result of the following:

- A lot of metadata files/folders in ~/.local/share/syncdaemon/fsm leading to syncdaemon startup taking more than 2 minutes - bug [LP:683116](https://launchpad.net/bugs/683116).

You may want to cleanup syncdaemon directories by running the following command while syncdaemon is *not* running. The first one will give you the info about how many directories can be cleaned up:

```
find ~/.local/share/ubuntuone/syncdaemon -depth -type d -empty | wc -l
```

And this one will delete empty directories:

```
find ~/.local/share/ubuntuone/syncdaemon -depth -type d -empty -delete
```

After that running the first command should return 0 as the amount of directories. Subsequent starts should be faster.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I am trying the line count, and the HDD is already for 5 minutes active, so there seem to be quite a lot of dirs to look through. The only line in my syncdeamon.log was [code]2010-12-05 20:59:44,041 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.fsm - INFO - loading updated metadata[/code]

Comment: But that would mean that u1 still does not scale. What do I buy 20 or 40 Gigs for if I can only upload a handful of files before the syncdeamon can't handle it anymore :(

Comment: The answer I got from the first bash command was only "3", that does no seem very high...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be similar to this bug: http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntuone-client/+bug/672884

Comment: > So even after a fresh reboot I am unable to use u1sdtool to do anything... and since the "Sync with Ubuntu One" option has disappeared from the left click menu when in File Manager, I have NO way at all of adding new folders other than moving them into the Ubuntu One folder, which I really do not wish to do.

Comment: That is exactly what happened to me, thanks for the link. The right click option has disappeared and u1sdtool only throughs the error mentioned in the bug report.

Comment: I am affected too. This is exactly what happens in my last installation

Answer (score 1):

As rye pointed out this is caused by LP:683116

On other side, initial metadata loading is very slow, we are working on a new metadata format that will improve the startup time and lower disk usage at least by an order of magnitude.

The client in the [nightlies PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuone/+archive/nightlies) has a new metadata format which is a an order of magnitude faster than the "old" (file shelf) format.